# Custom status bar when application is in background

Tags: ios, background, statusbar

In iOS 7, is it possible to modify the status bar when the application enters background? I want to achieve something similar to the "in-call" phone application background mode.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is impossible. When the app is in background you can only use the BACKGROUND MODE: Audio and AirPlay, Location uodates, Voice over IP, Newstand downloads, External acessory communication, Uses Bluetooth, Acts as Bluetooth, Background fetch and Remote notifications.